# Proper way to scanf and printf a size_t variable (platform independent)

Tags: c, printf, scanf, size-t

I've read several articles on this topic, but some say that the way it should be done depends on the architecture and system you're in (Windows/Linux), so is there a proper way to do this platform independent?

Comment: [C99 specifies the `zu` format specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: I think Microsoft has *finally* caught up with the standard `%zu` in VS2015.

Comment: Use `"%zu"`, `"%zo"`, `"%zx"`, or `"%zX"` depending on what base you prefer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%zu` for `size_t`, with

- `%z` for length, and
- `%u` for unsigned

Details can be found at

> 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function
>
> 6 The flag characters and their meanings are:
>
> ...
>
> **z**
> Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a size_t or the corresponding signed integer type argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed integer type corresponding to size_t argument.